# iOS7, Sign in and post to twitter without Twitter App/ Add new ACAccount

Tags: ios, twitter, acaccount

So I'm trying to integrate twitter with the app I'm working on. The flow I'm looking for is one in which the user is prompted to enter his twitter username and password just once, and then anytime the user wants to post to twitter he can do so by entering text into a textfield and clicking a "send" button - no other hurdles.

I know how to accomplish this if the user already has the twitter app installed with an associated account - you can retrieve the account form the ACAccountStore. But what do you do when the user does NOT have the twitter app installed/no twitter account in ACAccountStore? Is there a way to add a new ACAccount using the username and password I have the user enter in-app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can then use the twitter framework for setting the account with in the app or you can force the user directly from with in the app to goto setting and set up an account for twitter..